# Is this tensor identity true?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, cross-product

If We have two vectors $\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{b}$ and a symmetric positive definite Matrix $\boldsymbol{M}$
I was wondering if the expression $((\boldsymbol{a}\times \boldsymbol{b}) \cdot \boldsymbol{M}) \times \boldsymbol{a}$ was equivalent to $(\boldsymbol{a}\times \boldsymbol{b} \times \boldsymbol{a}) \cdot \boldsymbol{M}$ thanks  in advance for the help!

Comment: What is $a\times b\times a$?

Comment: Should that be $a \otimes b$ and $a \otimes b \otimes a$?

Comment: It's the same of $(\boldsymbol{a}\times \boldsymbol{b}) \times \boldsymbol{a}$ which is itself equal to  $\boldsymbol{a}\times (\boldsymbol{b} \times \boldsymbo{a})$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: you cancelled your answer but you're not posting a corrected one?